# how to implement two user types (seller and customer or buyer) using django allauth like fiverr?

Tags: django, django-models, e-commerce, django-allauth

I am working on a web e-commerce project where there will be two types of user (seller, customer). I have been wondering how to implement the logic like fiverr seller and buyer. I have created a user account with two flags yet (is_seller, is_customer).

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
is_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

objects = UserManager()
```

I want 2 users (seller and customer). A seller can request for a customer account as well (so same email will be used for login and signup) and vice versa.
what will be the best approach to this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If they all share the same data fields then this might be the simplest way to do it. I'd only recommend multiple user models if there'll be different data captured. In that case, you could [extend the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

Comment: some data fields will be different like shipping address, company name etc. Moreover how can i switch between the two like fiverr

Comment: Switch between the 2 in what way, like different login pages? Or that the user can switch profiles? I don't use Fiverr so you need to explain this more.

Comment: as buyers only see stuff to buy like products etc and seller see stuff like his/her products and other sellers too, so a link to switch between the two states.